# What do developers need to consider before choosing a Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

If there's a better StackExchange for this question, feel free to migrate it.

Because I"m interested in developing Windows Phone apps, I'm about to switch phones.  Having never developed phone apps for any platform before, what features do I need to consider?

I'm worried about some phones being locked down to the point that I cannot do native development.  Is that a concern?

What other concerns that I don't have, should I have?  Things I would not have known about until doing phone development?

Is there a site that covers these concerns?  I could not find it with a couple casual searches.

Comment: Also, on reconsideration, I fear this question will be marked 'unanswerable' and closed.  But I appreciate answers regardless.

Answer (score 2):

The benefit of developing for Windows Phone is that Microsoft has standard minimum hardware requirements that all windows phone devices must meet. So for the most part you should be fine with any phone you choose. Here are a few things to consider though.

Most devices have either 512MB of RAM, or a 1GB or more of RAM. If you are planning on developing games and want any phone to be capable of playing your game you may be better off getting a 512MB device so that you can be sure the game runs well on the lower end hardware.

Almost all phones have both a front and rear facing camera, I believe the Nokia Lumia 520 is the only one that does not have a front-facing camera, but this phone is one of the most popular devices, especially in emerging markets.

If you want to make use of any Nokia APIs you may want to get a Nokia Lumia device. APIs like Nokia Mix Radio and I believe the HERE Maps APIs will be restricted to Nokia phones.